# Make a legend fill up the full width within the fieldset

Tags: css, legend, fieldset

I would like to have a background for a `legend` field within a `fieldset`. And I want it to take up the full width, but only within the fieldset. If I use `legend {width: 100%}` it will be **wider** than the `fieldset`.

Here is an example, runnable in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jonas_io/TAvRF/):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
fieldset {
    border:0;
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}

legend {
    font-weight:bold;
    background: orange;
    width: 100%
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset>
    <legend>Legend</legend>
    Content of Fieldset
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I can make the `legend` only fill up the width within the `fieldset`?

Comment: It's not wider on my Firefox... EDIT: Oh, it is wider on my Chrome >.<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/TAvRF/1/

You can use [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing):

```
legend {
    font-weight:bold;
    background: orange;
    width: 100%;

    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Then you can add `padding`: http://jsfiddle.net/TAvRF/5/

Although, just setting `padding: 0` and forgetting about `box-sizing: border-box` seems to work for me.. http://jsfiddle.net/TAvRF/6/

Comment: Thanks, it was great to be able to use `padding: 5px` in combination.

Comment: Good to know it's currently supported with all current major browser versions too, not sure if you want to watch out for the legacy ones: [caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing)

Comment: What about padding for fieldset contents?

Comment: @pgreen2 what I generally do is place a `<div>` inside the fieldset with the content. That tag can be padded exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a simple padding problem, I think you can easily solve it using a reset or setting the padding in the `legend`:

```
legend {
    font-weight:bold;
    background: orange;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;       /* added just in case... */
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this also solved the problem. But when using `box-sizing: border-box;` I was able to use custom padding to.